Make VS Code Flatpak version be able to use fonts from ~/.fonts
I've recently replaced RPM VS Code with Flatpak VS Code on my laptop with Fedora 40. However, I haven't been able to set my font correctly since VS Code doesn't seem to pick up font files in the ~/.fonts directory.
How can I make VS Code able to use fonts from my home directory?

https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html
